# Swift : View in a UIScrollView is unable to detect touch

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

So I have A `UIButton` in a `UIView` within a `UIScrollView` within a `UIViewController` within a `UIScrollView`.. that is whole lot of layers I know but that was required. But the result I got is that the `UIButton` cannot be tapped because the touch can't be detected on the button. ScrollViews are working perfectly but the elements in the final layer are not detecting touches.

The Layers are as follow:

```
UIViewController
~UIScrollView
~~UIViewController
~~~UIScrollView
~~~~UIView
~~~~~UIButton
```

Kindly tell me how can I detect the touch on the last UIView?

Comment: see the frames of all your view by set background color , see clips to bounds of all

Answer (score 2):

you should debug view hierarchy by clicking `debug view hierarchy button`

[image]    look like this.

So you come to know that your button actually get touch events or it is hidden by other views.

**Update :**

I am uploading another screenshot

[image]

You have to run your project then you will able to see this button above console pane.

You can refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html) for more details.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Where is this button in xcode? I am unable to find it. thanks

Comment: Check my update in answer. you need to run your project in simulator then after you will find it above console

Answer (score 0):

1. To solve your current problem, you need to iterate through all gestures on each super view and call [`requireGestureRecognizerToFail`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail:) for relevant gestures on subviews. This way you make sure that the subviews get the touches 'first' and superviews handle only those touches which are ignored or not recognize by subviews for whatever reason. (I know this sounds as ridiculous as having a view hierarchy like *UIViewController -> UIScrollView -> UIViewController -> UIScrollView -> UIView -> UIButton*)
2. It seems unlikely that you could not have solved your visual design using either `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`. So reconsider!! It will save you a lot of such issues.

Comment: How should I call 'requireGestureRecognizerToFail' function in any class? couldn't find help through the apple documentation.
also, I have used UICollectionView in the same project but that was not helping for the above scenario. Thanks